# vb.net server caching on webrequest

Tags: .net, vb.net, caching, random, webrequest

There seems to be a problem when i try to cache information returned via a webrequest.

For testing purposes i set up 2 pages one to generate a random number with server caching set, and another to call said page in a loop and dump the information onto the page so you can see if the information has been cached.

If i manually load the random number page and then the test page, caching works fine, but if the page is just called via the loop and i haven't previously loaded the page manually then the caching doesn't take effect.

Here's the code for both pages

Random number generator :

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%@ OutputCache VaryByParam="*" Duration="60" %>

<script runat="server">
    Dim len As String = ""

    Sub page_load()
        len = Request.QueryString("length")
        If IsNumeric(len) = False Then len = 5
        Response.Write(Rnd(CInt(len)))
    End Sub
</script>
```

Test call :

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="system.net" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>

<script runat="server">
    Sub page_load()
        Response.Write(gen_rnd() & "<br/>")
    End Sub

    Function gen_rnd() As String
        gen_rnd = ""

        Dim url As String = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
        url = url.Replace(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath), "")
        url = url & "gen_random.aspx?length=2"

        Dim wbrq As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
        wbrq.Method = "GET"
        wbrq.ContentLength = 0

        Dim wbrs As WebResponse = wbrq.GetResponse()

        Dim sr As StreamReader
        ' Read the returned data   
        wbrs = wbrq.GetResponse()
        sr = New StreamReader(wbrs.GetResponseStream)
        gen_rnd = sr.ReadToEnd.Trim
        sr.Close()

        Return gen_rnd
    End Function
</script>
```

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated, i use several webrequests in my site and only just realised none of them are actually being cached!